# Как использовать полученные из input данные?

Tags: javascript, dom, addeventlistener

```
Всем привет! Есть такой html:
```

```js
  
//В js файле получаю данные input:

const getInput = document.querySelector(".input1");
getInput.placeholder = "type here name of car";
const getBtn = document.querySelector(".button");

getBtn.addEventListener("click", ()=> {
  let data = getInput.value;
  function makeNewObj(someData, someClass) {
    return new someClass(someData);
  }
  let result = makeNewObj(data, anyData);
  return result;
});

console.log(result); // тут ошибку выдает

//из другого файла экспортирую class anyData.

 class anyData {
  constructor(data) {
    this.data = data;
  }
}

//export {anyData};
```

```html
    <div>
      <input type="text" class="input1" />
      <button class="button">Enter</button>
    </div>
```

Всем этим занимаюсь исключительно в целях изучения export import.
Проблема в следующем. Обработчик на getBtn не хочет делать return result. Я хочу вводить данные в input. Нажимать на кнопку. Данные отправляются в функцию, которая из полученных данных делает экземпляр класса и, чтобы потом им можно было воспользоваться. Но, как я не кручу не верчу, браузер выдает, что result is not defined. Из чего делаю выводы, что из обработчика нельзя вывести данные? а если очень надо? наверняка, как-то это решается. не в консоль же выводить данные? а если ими надо как-то дальше воспользоваться? Вообщем, мне явно не хватает знаний в этом вопросе. Поэтому прошу помочь) Заранее спасибо!

Comment: `console.log(result)` у вас переменная result не определена

Comment: она же определена в обработчике события. а как определить?) console.log у меня в тексте кода вообще не причем. он там лишь для того, чтобы показать, что result я не могу использовать вне обработчика. а мне надо использовать, если это вообще возможно.

Comment: console.log (result) я могу поставить в обработчике и тогда все будет выводиться. это понятно. не понятно, как использовать result за пределами по сути функции. почему return не работает? вот в чем проблема)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вариант 1. Определить переменную result в глобальной области видимости

```
let result;
getBtn.addEventListener("click", ()=> {
  let data = getInput.value;
  function makeNewObj(someData, someClass) {
    return new someClass(someData);
  }
  result = makeNewObj(data, anyData);
  show();
});

function show() {
  console.log(result)
}
```

Вариант 2. Передать result как параметр в другую функцию

```
function takeResult(arg) {
  console.log(arg);
}

getBtn.addEventListener("click", ()=> {
  let data = getInput.value;
  function makeNewObj(someData, someClass) {
    return new someClass(someData);
  }
  result = makeNewObj(data, anyData);
  takeResult(result)
});
```

Можно так же из обработчика клика вызывать готовую функцию с полным кодом и при необходимости передавать событие клика в нее... 
Все зависит от конкретной задачи, которую вы хотите решить

Comment: Спасибо! с Вашей помощью разобрался!